# How can I center the text inside a text input vertically in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a custom text input component in React Native. I have two text inputs, but I was wondering what the best way to center the text inside the text input vertically.

I added a justifyContent: 'center'; to the parent container and this seems to work, but I was wondering if theres a better way to do this. I have provided my code.

```
const CustomInput = ({ value, setValue, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={styles.input}
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: "#e8e8e8",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    height: "10%",
    borderStyle: "solid", // Default
    borderWidth: 2, // Border width
    borderColor: "blue", // Border color
  },

  input: {},
});
```

Comment: You can use `textAlignVertical: 'center'`

Comment: I think thats an android only property.

Comment: there is multiple way to do that see which fits you `flex: 1`  or  `alignItems: "center"`(Center vertically), and also  `paddingVertical: 10` (with this center the input vertically)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it should work.
I added alignItems: “center”

```js
const CustomInput = ({ value, setValue, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={styles.input}
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center", // Vertically center the content
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: "#e8e8e8",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 10,
    height: 50, // Set the desired height here
    borderStyle: "solid", // Default
    borderWidth: 2, // Border width
    borderColor: "blue", // Border color
  },

  input: {},
});
```